# Is there a non backend/control-panel solution to changing email or password?

Tags: email, password

Does ExpressionEngine have a native way to change the email or password of the current user using a form in a template?

I am aware that you can do it in the EE Control Panel Backend but I am looking for a solution that will work in a frontend template.

NOTE: About the password, I am not talking about the password lost/reset feature. I am aware of that solution. I am looking specifically to be able to change passwords on the spot rather than relying on that feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a boat load of options:

FreeMember: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/freemember

Stand Alone Member Edit: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/stand-alone-member-edit

OR find some paid for modules: http://devot-ee.com/search/results?keywords=member&addon_version_support=ee2

Comment: So there isn't a native way to do it then? I have to use add-ons?

Comment: No. There used to be something in the forum module which allowed users access to edit stuff but the templates were horrid. But you need the forum module. Both modules above are free and well supported.

Comment: In the end, I used Freemember for the email change and [this solution](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/209284/#978552) for the password change.

Comment: Freemember supports changing the password as well. See https://github.com/expressodev/freemember/blob/master/docs/update_profile_tag.md#example

Answer (score 0):

I don't *think* that you **need** to use add-ons. Just take the markup of the password reset form and rework it to fit in with what you need.

Creating the initial form is simple enough. For instance (markup straight from the form with the {XID_HASH} tag used.

```
<form action="admin.php?S=0&amp;D=cp&amp;C=login&amp;M=send_reset_token" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="XID" value="{XID_HASH}" />

    <dl>
        <dt>Submit your email address:</dt>
        <dd><input type="text" name="email" value="" style="width:100%" size="35" dir="ltr" id="email" maxlength="80" autocomplete="off"  /></dd>
    </dl>

    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" /> <span><a href="admin.php?S=0&amp;D=cp&amp;C=login">Return to login</a></span></p>

</form>
```

I'm not sure if you can specify a redirect to display a custom page once this form is submitted. I'm sure I've done it in the past and had the full login/password reset system as custom templates.

However, as mentioned, there are a few add-ons to handle all this anyway and, at least in the case of Freemember (and possibly others), they're free and easy to use so why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I don't think this is what I needed. As I mentioned in my question, I am not looking for the password reset feature. I want to a form to change the password on the spot.